# Eclipse doesn't import java libraries on cold start, plus other compiling errors

Tags: java, android, windows, eclipse

Eclipse is giving me a few problems.

After a cold start and the loading of android libs, Eclipse underline the import statements or says that java.lang.Object couldn't be found.
Closing it and reopening often fix the problem. If it doesn't, another close-open fix it definitely. But it shows at each cold-start.
It also gives

"The type java.lang.Enum cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files"

"The project cannot be build until build path errors are resolved"

But if i restart the build path errors and the enum problem are not show any more(sometimes the enum proble got fixed some time after eclipse's loading finished)

"Project 'xxx' is missing required source folder: 'gen' "

that should be generated automatically generated while building, and still restarting will fix them

In addition, in many projects, while building or cleaning, eclipse says that it couldn't delete the bin/. directory. I noticed that that directory is read-only, and if i try to remove the attribute(even from dos), it immediately return to read-only.

This problems aren't show-stoppers, i still can code and i still can get my apps exported, but it is quite annoying to have to restart eclipse a few times before being able to use it(and eclipse isn't that fast at opening), and i would really know how to fix it.

I searched in the net a bit, but i dind't found nothing useful or that worked.

Is there a way to fix them?
I didn't "unistalled"(it is just stored in a directory) Eclipse, since i should then reinstall android sdk, mercurial plugin, and re download and set up a few libraries i use in quite all my project, and i really hope there is another way.

final notes:
everything works when this problems doesn't show: the app works, logcat too, the right device is used to install the app, so i think java and android sdks are installed just right

Comment: Have you tried running `Project > Clean` then `Project > Build All`? Another common issue involves the old 'gen' folder not getting overwritten, so many people recommend deleting it before building again.

Comment: @ewall Yes, already done, but the problem persists..

Comment: I figured as much... but it's a common enough issue that it was worth mentioning. Sorry I don't have much more to offer!

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem before so I just saved my projects to a different file and uninstalled everything ( java, android sdk, eclipse ). When I reinstalled it all I put the android sdk on the root of my c drive as I have a windows machine and then instead of picking where java was installed I let it do its own thing. I dont use a mercurial plug in but your "read only" problem could be related to that. Its possible your downloading files that are "read only" and there for you have no way to alter them. Im guessing since you said youve been programing you already know how to set the build paths and stuff. It might just be where everything is installed or something silly like privilege settings on your machine.

What were you using the mercurial plug in for anyway? just curious :)

Comment: i had the same thoughts at first. The problem is that quite all the directories of the pc are read only (yes, quite weird). I'll keep in mind the reinstalling option .
Btw i use it for http://www.andengine.org/
No documentation, but once you get how to work is a really nice engine

Comment: Are you using your own pc or one at your work? If its yours then you just need to change the settings of your windows account to admin and then change the settings of the folders/files from read to write. I messed with the andengine for a bit but I think I used a stand alone mercurial or something like tortoiseSVN to create a copy of the files so I could rewrite over them if I needed to.

Comment: Home. My account is already admin but the problem continue to exist. Btw i don't think it is the mercurial plugin the problem, i noticed i have this "behaviour" in all the directories of the pc, and i can modify the engine sources like every other file..

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the java lib in your project or? For a couple of weeks ago I sat with an project where i absolutly needed some of the methods, so because android just have some of the java lib I imported the need libs and used that.